# Java richfaces fileUpload document.domain

Tags: java, jsf, iframe, richfaces, seam

I have a page that is in an iframe where `document.domain` has been set.

This page contains a richfaces 3.3.4 `fileUpload` component, but uploads fail because it creates a new iframe to perform the upload which can't then communicate to its parent page because `document.domain` has been set in the outer, but not in the `fileUpload` inner one.

The error is:

`FileUpload.js:22 Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://example.com". The frame requesting access set "document.domain" to "example.com", but the frame being accessed did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.`

Is there a way to make it work? Like e.g. add a custom script to the content of the uploader iframe so that I can set the `document.domain` to match the parent?

Comment: You'd have to overwrite the component code. I don't know if you can obtain direct access to the method that creates the iframe.

Comment: Thanks, that confirms my thinking. We're going to try to create a custom component that uses the same source code but with a mod.